# Paste code snippet into vscode from a Electron app/third-party application

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

Is it possible to paste snippet code directly into vscode from a third-party application like an Electron app? Example is the following code:

```
const code = "var $0 = $1;";

clipboard.writeText(code, 'clipboard')
app.hide()

const newWin = await activeWindow()

// simulate CTRL+V / CMD+V
setTimeout(() => {
   if (newWin.owner.bundleId === 'com.microsoft.VSCode') {
      console.log('is vscode')
   }
   robot.keyTap('v', process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'command' : 'control')
}, 100)
```

If I created that code variable as a snippet in vscode and then used it inside vscode, then vscode would use `$0` and `$1` as placeholders, but if I just paste that code directly into vscode then it's not using the placeholders...

Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

you have to use the function `vscode.TextEditor.insertSnippet()`

Comment: Yes but I get an error if I try to install `vscode` inside the Electron app? 
**Uncaught Exception: Error: Cannot find module 'vscode'...** 

Even though I have installed the `vscode` package.